# Apache Commons Exec: executable not in PATH

Tags: apache-commons-exec

How do I execute a program which is NOT on the system PATH (and I don't want to put it there)? Eg. the simplest example:

```
String program = "/my/path/to/my/program";
new DefaultExecutor().execute(CommandLine.parse(program));
```

throws

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/my/path/to/my/program" (in directory ".")
```

(The same is true with programs on the PATH, eg. "/usr/bin/ls" fails with the same message.)

Note: I do not want to change the working directory.

Answer (score -1):

The path to my program was wrong (and `ls` is not in `/usr/bin`), but the error message mislead me - it didn't look for the executable in the working directory at all.